# How to add multi-tenancy using Next Auth and Keycloak provider

Tags: reactjs, next.js, keycloak, multi-tenant, next-auth

I've been trying to use [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) and [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) together, but I'm falling when using multi-realms login, using a single keycloak provider I couldn't change `clientSecret` and `issuer` options at runtime, so I tried to add multiples keycloak providers with a different `id` per realm, it works and I can use the react hook to select the right realm:

[...nextauth].ts

```
const realms = [
    {
        id: 'abc',
        clientId: 'nextjs',
        clientSecret: 'asfasdfdfasdfdasfasfddsf',
        issuer: 'http://localhost:8080/realms/abc',
    },
    {
        id: 'xyz',
        clientId: 'nextjs',
        clientSecret: 'ssdfsdfsdfasdfasdfasdfasfdsdf',
        issuer: 'http://localhost:8080/realms/xyz',
    }
];
```

providers:

```
    export default NextAuth({
    providers: realms.map((realm) => KeycloakProvider({
        id: realm.id,
        clientId: realm.clientId,
        clientSecret: realm.clientSecret,
        issuer: realm.issuer
    })),
});
```

My biggest problem is that I can't include more providers/realms configurations at runtime, it would be nice if I could use an secure end-point to fetch those keycloak configs... so if someone could help me out, showing me some guide how to achieve it, any help is welcome!

My I'm pretty new to NextJS and you can check my [full-project-code](https://github.com/jonasjuni/nextjs/blob/main/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found a solution that seems to work!
In the `[...nextauth].tsx` file, instead of directly exporting the NextAuth function, use a handler just like any other api, and then you can control the providers dynamically. Example:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // getCustomers is a custom function that gets all your customers from the database or wherever
  const customers = await getCustomers() 
  
  // Build a list of all the providers
  const providers = customers.map(customer => KeycloakProvider({
    id: ...
    name: ...
    ...
  }))

  // Return the same NextAuth function, but pass the req and res parameters so it can return the response
  return NextAuth(req, res, {
    providers,
    pages: {
      ...
    }    
    ...
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eitan! I'm doing smth similar: https://github.com/jonasjuni/nextjs/blob/main/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.ts